# Редактирование раздела справки Что это означает если ответа «принят»?

Tags: обсуждение, справка, нет-в-transifex

[Что это означает если ответа «принят»?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Есть раздел справки. Заголовок явно содержит ошибку. Давайте его исправим, и заодно отредактируем и по возможности улучшим текст раздела.

Comment: Хм, а мне почему-то дало убрать «хвост» вопроса.

Comment: @VladD: убрать - можно, а сразу опубликовать - нельзя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Постарался не сильно менять смысл.

---

## Что означает «принятие» ответа?

Если пользователю, задавшему вопрос, подходит какой-то из ответов, он может его «принять». Например, ответ может натолкнуть автора вопроса на решение проблемы. Или просто он может понравиться больше других ответов. После принятия ответа слева от него появляется зелёная галочка.

Принятый ответ — не обязательно лучший! То, что автор принял ответ, значит лишь что этот ответ помог *автору вопроса*. Даже если позже поступят новые, более правильные ответы, автор вопроса может оставить принятым тот ответ, который ему нравится. А может, наоборот, позже изменить своё мнение и принять другой ответ.

Если вы принимаете...

- ...ответ другого пользователя, то вы получаете +2 балла репутации, а автор принятого ответа — +15 баллов. Принятый ответ будет показываться сверху списка ответов. Исключение: при принятии ответа в [общем вопросе](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) репутация не изменяется
- ...[свой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), то ваша репутация не изменяется, а ответ при этом не будет перенесён в верхнюю часть списка. Принять свой ответ можно через 48 часов после публикации вопроса.

---

P.S.: нужен раздел справки про общие вопросы, покамест есть только ссылка на англоязычную статью.

Comment: Вроде бы 48 часов после публикации вопроса, а не ответа. Надо бы проверить.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Спрошу-ка у Николаса в чате.

Comment: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1473/181472

Comment: @NickVolynkin: методом эксперимента :) Доказано!

Comment: Попробую-ка гуманизировать текст. Длинные предложения не всегда хорошо читаются.

Comment: думаю, это хорошая идея.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: обновил текст

Comment: тоже немного подправил.