# Опечатки и стилистические ошибки в справке по сайту

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено, локализация, справка, нет-в-transifex

[Опечатка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) в заголовке:

> если ответ**а** «принят»?

---

Не та [буква](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) :

> "готовым бе**з**корыстно помогать"

Должно быть

> бе**с**корыстно

---

Стилистическая [ошибка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators):

> что может не понравиться всем пользователям.

Если не понравится, то сразу всем? :) Нужно перефразировать. Например:

> что может не всем пользователям понравиться.

Comment: Не нашёл строки в transifex, поставил метку.

Comment: @VladD: конечно, это же справка.

Comment: [meta-tag:перевод-содержимого] в данном случае неподходящая метка. Она относится к переводу содержимого сайта (то есть вопросов и ответов) между различными языками и сайтами сети Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не та [буква](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) :

> "готовым бе**з**корыстно помогать"

Этого вроде бы пока что не замечали, спасибо. Рано или поздно процесс улучшения дойдёт и до этого раздела справки.

---

> если ответ**а** «принят»?

Про это есть целый вопрос, там нужно переделать не только это место:

[Редактирование раздела справки Что это означает если ответа «принят»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1470/181472)

---

Стилистическая [ошибка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators):

> модераторы стремятся действовать во благо сайта, но иногда они ошибаются или вынуждены идти на компромисс, что может не понравиться всем пользователям.

Тоже есть вопрос про редактирование целого раздела: [Улучшение раздела справки «Кто такие модераторы и какова их роль?»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1648/181472)

У нас принят перевод «участники», а не «пользователи»:

> модераторы стремятся действовать во благо сайта, но иногда они ошибаются или вынуждены идти на компромисс, что может понравиться не всем участникам.

Comment: Неужели так сложно убрать букву за полтора месяца?

Comment: @alexolut: там не только буква, а вся статья переделывалась. А изменение каждого слова не получится сразу применять, т.к. редактирование справки требует времени Nicolas Chabanovsky. По двум уже отредактированным статьям я отправил ему напоминание в чате.

Comment: Не очень пока в курсе всех местных сложностей, но главное, что внимание привлечено, обсуждение ведется, стало быть и результат должен быть рано или поздно. Лучше, конечно, рано :)